# PHP not retrieving cookies

Tags: php, cookies

This PHP code is supposed to write to a file in a folder specified by a cookie:

```
    $user = $_COOKIE["username"];
if( $xml = file_get_contents("$user/docs.xml") ) {
```

But it just says the file `/docs.xml` (not specifying the folder) just the file and not the cookie value, apparently doesn't exist, because it's not getting the cookie but ***why?***

***Could it be that I'm trying to get it from a different domain?***

Comment: Are you sure the cookie is set for the appropriate domain and path? Can you show the code that sets the cookie? All the rest of the coe you've posted seems irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar All the resources I saw on PHP cookies said I just needed  `$_COOKIE["username"];`

Comment: Cookie value empty, show code where you set cookie and how

Comment: This is where I got the code: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: You can't retrieve a cookie if it wasn't set somewhere else. And cookies are specific to a particular domain and directory path.

Comment: How do I tell it to do that in PHP? Do you have any resources I could check out?

Comment: Try `var_dump($user);` and/or `if( $xml = file_get_contents($user."/docs.xml")`

Comment: Can I please see the code you used to setcookie, and if it located in the same folder?

Comment: You are using cookies directly for find out usename?
That's not a good idea! try using $_SESSION instead, or at least, hash the poor username!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the cookie like so

```
setcookie("Name", "Value", $time, "/");
```

The / at the end make sure the cookie works throughout the whole site, not just the folder where it was set.